# Observable Check isLoading?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2

typescript

```
export class BossListComponent implements OnInit {

  bossObservable: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bossObservable = this.getBoss('/world_boss');
  }

  getBoss(listPath): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list(listPath).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

html

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">Loading...</div>
<div *ngFor="let boss of bossObservable | async">
   //loop boss
<div>
```

This my code, I'm newbie to angularjs.

How can add loading page when data is loading.

I tried to use subscribe but i can't, please, thank.

full code: https://github.com/Aquzohr/world-boss-timer-bdoth

Comment: i'm not used Services.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference